# Parse array of dictionaries of json in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

i wanted to parse this json using this way

```
{"img":[{"id":"44","name":"\u0625\u0628\u0631\u0627\u0647\u064a\u0645 \u0627\u0644\u0639\u0631\u064a\u0641\u064a","type":"\u0627\u0646\u0627 \u0627\u062a\u0639\u0644\u0645","img":"27039_01355548242.png","school":"\u0625\u0628\u0631\u0627\u0647\u064a\u0645 \u0627\u0644\u0639\u0631\u064a\u0641\u064a","isshow":"1","tarteb":"0","date":"29\/1\/2015 01:15","mob":"16544541321"}]}
```

i wrote this code to parse it

```
 NSArray * array = [[NSArray alloc]init];
array = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseObject options:kNilOptions error:nil];
NSDictionary * dic =array[indexPath.row]; //here  is error
NSLog(@"%@",dic);
NSDictionary * info = dic[@"img"];
cell.name.text = info[@"name"];
cell.date.text =info[@"date"];
cell.schoolName.text= info[@"school"];
cell.mobile.text= info[@"mob"];
```

then i got this error

```
[__NSCFDictionary objectAtIndex :]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7c986db0
```

Comment: `JSONObjectWithData` returns you `NSDictionary` not `NSArray`

Comment: I think it returns array
of didctionaries and img is key for this dictionary

Comment: plesse let me know if you have any issues

Comment: @user3045517, no. Your error states, that you send invalid message to `NSDictionary`. So, it returns `NSDictionary` for sure, and `array` contains pointer to `NSDictionary`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSDictionary *jsonDictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc] init];
jsonDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseObject options:kNilOptions error:nil];
NSArray *imageArray = jsonDictionary[@"img"];

NSDictionary *firstObject = imageArray[0];
cell.name.text = firstObject[@"name"];
cell.date.text =firstObject[@"date"];
cell.schoolName.text= firstObject[@"school"];
cell.mobile.text= firstObject[@"mob"];
```

and If there are multiple rows in json,Like:

```
{"img":[{"id":"44","name":"\u0625\u0628\u0631\u0627\u0647\u064a\u0645 \u0627\u0644\u0639\u0631\u064a\u0641\u064a","type":"\u0627\u0646\u0627 \u0627\u062a\u0639\u0644\u0645","img":"27039_01355548242.png","school":"\u0625\u0628\u0631\u0627\u0647\u064a\u0645 \u0627\u0644\u0639\u0631\u064a\u0641\u064a","isshow":"1","tarteb":"0","date":"29\/1\/2015 01:15","mob":"16544541321"},{"id":"45","name":"\u0625\u0628\u0631\u0627\u0647\u064a\u0645 \u0627\u0644\u0639\u0631\u064a\u0641\u064a","type":"\u0627\u0646\u0627 \u0627\u062a\u0639\u0644\u0645","img":"27039_01355548242.png","school":"\u0625\u0628\u0631\u0627\u0647\u064a\u0645 \u0627\u0644\u0639\u0631\u064a\u0641\u064a","isshow":"1","tarteb":"0","date":"29\/1\/2015 01:15","mob":"16544541321"},{"id":"46","name":"\u0625\u0628\u0631\u0627\u0647\u064a\u0645 \u0627\u0644\u0639\u0631\u064a\u0641\u064a","type":"\u0627\u0646\u0627 \u0627\u062a\u0639\u0644\u0645","img":"27039_01355548242.png","school":"\u0625\u0628\u0631\u0627\u0647\u064a\u0645 \u0627\u0644\u0639\u0631\u064a\u0641\u064a","isshow":"1","tarteb":"0","date":"29\/1\/2015 01:15","mob":"16544541321"}]}
```

then use this approach, if you need to show `id:44` in zeroth row,`id:45` in first row,`id:46` in second row,...Of table view.

```
//In View Did Load
NSMutableArray *tableDataSource = [NSMutableArray new];
for (int i = 0; i < imageArray.count; i++)
{
    NSDictionary *rowDataDictionary = imageArray[i];
    [tableDataSource addObject:rowDataDictionary];
}


//In Cell For Row
NSDictionary *rowData = tableDataSource[indexPath.row];
cell.name.text = rowData[@"name"];
cell.date.text =rowData[@"date"];
cell.schoolName.text= rowData[@"school"];
cell.mobile.text= rowData[@"mob"];
```

`JsonObjectWithData` Returns Dictionary, and you should parse the data according to structure of JSON.

Hope this Helps,

Answer (score 0):

As it shown above, JsonObjectWithData returns NSDictionary object, and you should use valueForKey method for taking value which you need.

```
NSDictionary *jsonDictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc] init];
jsonDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseObject options:kNilOptions error:nil];
NSMutableArray *valueForImgLabel = [jsonDictionary valueForKey:@"img"];
```

If you have too much value for one element in your JSON Response object, like this ;

```
{
Name = "Mr. Hope";
Gender = "Male";
Age = 29;
ImageList =     (
            {
        Name = "Front side";
        Image = "11111.JPG";
        Order = 1;
        Date = "07/07/2014";
            },
            {
        Name = "Left Side";
        Image = "22222.JPG";
        Order = 1;
        Date = "10/28/2015";
            });
}
```

You can take all ImageList elements,convertibly, using valueForkey like this;

```
NSMutableArray *imageListInJSONFile = [jsonDictionary valueForKey:@"ImageList"][0];
```